# Triangle with incircle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, no-computers

This question is from the German mathematics competition [Känguru der Mathematik](http://www.mathe-kaenguru.de/wettbewerb/index.html). In this competition students have to solve 30 mathematical tasks like this in 90 minutes without calculator. Actually they are given 5 possible answers, but for this community a bit of additional challenge does not hurt.

[image]

You are given a triangle $ABC$ with $\overline{AB} = 3$, $\overline{BC} = 5$ and $\overline{CA} = 6$ (image not to scale). The line segment $DE$ is tangential to the incircle of the triangle $ABC$. What is the perimeter of the triangle $CDE$?

Comment: Usually when talking about triangles, we call the sum of the edges the perimeter, and reserve the word circumference for the perimeter of a circle.

Comment: @micsthepick Thank you, that was new to me. I changed it in the question.

Comment: It is not necessarily incorrect, I would think that perimeter is used in this case more often.

Comment: @micsthepick I read it as the circumference of the circumcircle, which completely changes the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a puzzle but I want to share the answer:

First, we know that

> The $|AB|$ is equal to $3$.

So

> $|AF|+|BG|$ has to be equal to $3$ as well since the tangents to the circle from a point has to be equal to each other.

[image]

Moreover, E and D point location does not matter but the sum

> $|EF|+|DG|$ is equal to $|DE|$ with the same rule. which is a part of the circumference of the big triangle except the grey part $|EC|+|DC|$.

As a result, whatever E and D point you choose, the circumference of $CDE$ will be

> Circumference of CDE = Circumference of ABC - 6 = $6+5+3-6=8$

Comment: Isn't it incorrect to say "circumference of CDE/ACD," since they are triangles? Isn't it  "perimeter," since circumference is a term used specifically for circles and similar shapes?

Answer (score 7):

If I were to simply solve this like a multiple choice question, I would consider the extreme case where the tangent is co-linear with AC or BC, the length will be twice the distance from C to either intersection between the circle and the triangle that is on a side that ends at C. the length of these such sides are always equal. using this fact you can set up some simultaneous equations and solve for c:

```
a+b=3 (x)
a+c=5 (y)
b+c=6 (z)
2*(a+b+c) = 14 (x+y+z)
a+b+c = 7 (i)
c = 4 (i-x)
```

c = 4 and 2*c = 8, therefore the answer is 8. As for a proof that It is the same in between the extremes, you can refer to other answers.

Comment: You still need to prove that the circumference is constant. Otherwise theoretically the multiple choice could come into play.

Comment: Wow, you are really fast. But as you have more than the average 3 minutes per question, could you also add your calculations that made you find $4$ as length between $C$ and the intersection between the triangle side and the incircle?

It would be even better with a proof that shows that this is true not only for this extreme position of the tangent.